# Auto numbering constraints in optimization problems

Tags: equations, numbering

The following code

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\setlength\arraycolsep{1.5pt}
\begin{array}{l@{\qquad} r c r c r}
(P)     & z(P) = \min   &  cx \\
        & \mathrm{s.t.} &  Ax & = & b \\
        &               &   x & \in &  X \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

produces a single equation number associated with the whole model as can be seen from the picture below.

[image]

How can I define a number for each constraint (without writing it myself)?
See example below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example compilable (MWE). And it may be helpful to add a drawing of what you want to achieve.

Comment: You may refer to: [How to number subequations separately from the main equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170574/how-to-number-subequations-separately-from-the-main-equation)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365894/is-it-possible-to-make-two-tags-for-the-same-equation

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses the `optidef` package. I appears to require writing the objective function differently to what was posted as an example. Otherwise, the function and the constraints are individually numbered.

The following examples illustrate four different usages, providing different alignments, and a long and short style of notation.

This is the result:

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[nocomma]{optidef}

\begin{document}

Short notation, alternative 1 layout for constraints
\begin{mini!}|s|[1]                   % mini! = minimize 
    {x}                               % optimization variable
    {z(P) = \min cx \label{eq:eq1}}   % objective function and label
    {\label{eq:Example1}}             % label for optimizatio problem
    {}                                % optimization result
    \addConstraint{Ax}{=b \label{eq:con1}}    % constraint 1
    \addConstraint{x}{\in X \label{eq:con2}}  % constraint 2
\end{mini!}

Short notation, alternative 2 layout for constraints
\begin{mini!}|s|[2]                   % mini! = minimize 
    {x}                               % optimization variable
    {z(P) = \min cx \label{eq:eq1}}   % objective function and label
    {\label{eq:Example1}}             % label for optimizatio problem
    {}                                % optimization result
    \addConstraint{Ax}{=b \label{eq:con1}}    % constraint 1
    \addConstraint{x}{\in X \label{eq:con2}}  % constraint 2
\end{mini!}

Short notation, alternative 3 layout for constraints
\begin{mini!}|s|[3]                   % mini! = minimize
    {x}                               % optimization variable
    {z(P) = \min cx \label{eq:eq1}}   % objective function and label
    {\label{eq:Example1}}             % label for optimizatio problem
    {}                                % optimization result
    \addConstraint{Ax}{=b \label{eq:con1}}    % constraint 1
    \addConstraint{x}{\in X \label{eq:con2}}  % constraint 2
\end{mini!}

Long notation, alternative 2 layout for constraints
\begin{mini!}|l|[2]                   % mini! = minimize 
    {x}                               % optimization variable
    {z(P) = \min cx \label{eq:eq1}}   % objective function and label
    {\label{eq:Example1}}             % label for optimizatio problem
    {}                                % optimization result
    \addConstraint{Ax}{=b \label{eq:con1}}    % constraint 1
    \addConstraint{x}{\in X \label{eq:con2}}  % constraint 2
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```